# Allow collapsing vote-count

Tags: feature-request, vote-count

This is a minor, OCD driven, request but that's never stopped me before...

After showing the vote counts for a post, I would like to re-collapse to the regular view. So far the only way I know to get this is to refresh the whole page. I think that another click on the expanded vote count should re-collapse the votes to the *normal* total.

Comment: This calls for a userscript

Comment: That has bothered me ever since it was introduced and I've been meaning to post exactly this for years. I know the vote counters still increment in real time when expanded, but I'd love to be able to collapse them. I wanted it when I wanted a way to 'mark' an answer I was going to try in the presence of 10+ answers, where the accepted answer wasn't the one I wanted.

Comment: There is a workaround: immediately vote and retract the vote. This doesn't really work if you already voted as your vote might be locked, and even if it's unlocked, it will relock the vote.

Comment: It already works that way in the iOS app.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog that way lies madness